# ArcGIS Javascript Legend widget does not show full color ramp

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology

Has anyone used the legend widget with raster map services? I have created a GP service that returns raster maps, but the legend is incomplete.

[image: Color ramp info]

The ArcGIS layer properties are shown here, and below how the legend looks in ArcMap TOC (left), REST services directory (middle), and result web map (right).

It looks like by default, there is only a high and low label. I added the Medium label manually before publishing, but the color ramp seems to be recalculated when you run the GP tool through the Javascript API.

Any ideas on how I can get the full color ramp to show up?

**Update**:
This has been logged as two bugs, see http://support.esri.com for more details:

BUG-000092784 : Running a Geoprocessing service at Rest endpoint and publishing the result as a map service causes the Legend color ramp values to change.

BUG-000092783 : Running a Geoprocessing service using the javascript API and adding the result map and legend to the application causes the medium value of the legend to disappear.

Comment: Does anyone know about legends on map services? I've had some help at https://geonet.esri.com/message/562496#562496, but it looks like map services that are connected to gp result services behave differently. Maybe the legend is not fully supported or I'll have to raise a support call, but I'd like to know either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing medium value issue (BUG-000092783) was fixed at version 3.16:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/new_v316.html

No update to the values changing issue though.